# Vapor Deployment -> ERROR: Repository not found

Tags: swift, git, vapor, server-side-swift

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Error: deploy failed.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a remote repo on GitHub or a similar service?

Answer (score 0):

If the repository is private, make sure that you send the private SSH to vapor https://docs.vapor.cloud/advanced/general/using-private-git/